# What is this Kenwood food processor attachment for?

Tags: equipment, food-processor

We've recently acquired a food processor, and can't work out for the life of us what this attachment does. The manual, and Googling, hasn't helped. Here's the attachment:

[image]

And here's the food processor (Kenwood FDP30)

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add a photo from the opposite angle?

Comment: The manual here calls it an emulsifying tool (#22 in the exploded parts diagram): https://www.kenwoodworld.com/Global/Instruction-Manuals/Food-Processors/Multipro-Compact/FDP300series/132062%20Iss%204%20FDP30%20multilingual.B5.pdf

Comment: @Lou ^ Also on p. 6 of that manual it looks like there's some speed and capacity recommendations for that; and talks about cream and mayo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will assume the other end of the attachment is not for cutting. It looks like a tool for emulsification. You can make sauces like mayonnaise using the attachment.

Edit:
The comment of @steve-chambers confirms that it indeed is an emulsification tool.